# Regex using | with sed

Tags: regex, sed

I am trying to remove "bad" characters from a string, but I can't seem to get it to act correctly.

My current command: if I was trying to remove e and l

```
sed -e "s/e|l//g" ...
```

This works exactly as expected though

```
sed -e "s/e//g"
```

So my main question is How do I match and replace multiple independent strings using  regex?

Comment: For your specific example, if you're looking for any instance of the letter e or l you want a character class `s/[el]//g`. Also I'd recommend adding the sed tag to this for more visibility. I'd do it but it'll probably be rejected as too minor.

Comment: @ChicagoRedSox You suggestion is correct.  Add it as an answer.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It makes sense and works for my purposes. Sed was just an example command though. I will probably still add the tag though.

Comment: @TheThirdOne for some blatant reputation farming - would you mind accepting the answer if it's what you need? Thanks.

Comment: To be clear - you CANNOT `match and replace multiple independent strings using regex` because you're asking for a tool that can match both strings and REs in the same operation and that does not exist. sed can ONLY match REs. If you want to match strings you can use fgrep or awk. If you want to match any of a set of strings with a single command execution, you can use awk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your specific example, if you're looking for any instance of the letter `e` or `l` you want a character class.  Say:

```
sed 's/[el]//g'
```

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, you cannot `match and replace multiple independent strings using regex` but here's how you can `match and replace multiple independent strings`, just not using a regex:

```
awk -v strings="foo,bar" '
BEGIN {
    split(strings,tmp,/,/) 
    for (i=1;i in tmp; i++)
        stringA[tmp[i]]
}
{
    for (string in stringA) {
        if ( start = index($0,string) ) {
             $0 = substr($0,1,start-1) "some other string" substr($0,start+length(string)+1)
        }
    }
    print
}
' file
```

Untested but the above should replace the strings "foo" and/or "bar" with the text "some other string".